# Is it possible to get last elements grouped with JPA and Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
name | rang
boo  | 4
boo  | 2
boo  | 1
foo  | 3
foo  | 1
zoo  | 2
zoo  | 1
```

I want to select through spring boot jpa:

```
name | rang
boo  | 4
foo  | 3
zoo  | 2
```

I do ofcause have a larger and more complex dataset, so the example is simplify.

I was hoping to find something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<FooDb, String> {
    Set< FooDb > findAllByNameAndMaxDate(String name);
}
```

Comment: Default query methods are purposed for simple operations on entities. `Group by` is not supported, you have to manually set `@Query("select .... group by ....")` annotation on a method to achieve desired SQL query analog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to do this [by using the `@Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

In your case it might look something like:

```
@Query("SELECT t.name, MAX(t.rang) FROM table t WHERE t.name=?1 GROUP BY t.name")
Set<FooDb> findAllByNameAndMaxDate(String name);
```

Without knowing what your data set looks like it's impossible for me to create the query here, but I hope this helps.

Comment: This approach doesn't work
@Query("SELECT t, MAX(t.rang) FROM table t GROUP BY t.name")
Set<FooDb> findAllByMaxDate();

Comment: as it is a  aggregate function